# Use client-side Google analytics to log server-side Django events

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, server-side

Does anyone have any best practice recommendations for using client side Google Analytics to log server side-triggered Django events? There are particularly granular server side events that I wish to log to GA from my Django webapp.

I am already using the Django messages framework for user-facing messages, so I am hesitant to overload it by trying to queue up GA messages that then get logged on the next user-facing page.  I could use session variables to do the same sort of thing, but that also feels somewhat cloogy. I'd rather implement a server-side call but there's no elegant solution there either, so I may as well stick to the standard GA APIs.

Has anyone cascaded server-side events forward to the client Google Analytics logging using Django/Python or another web framework, and what do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GA has a pretty nice upcoming feature called the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). It allows you to push data from server side using simple POST requests. It is still at a developer preview stage, but you can request access to try it out.